# Select best score per quiz and sum points leaderboard

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum, max

I have MySql table that look like this

```
quiz_id | user_id | points 
--------+---------+--------
1       | 1       | 2         
1       | 1       | 7         
3       | 1       | 7       
2       | 1       | 5      
1       | 2       | 7      
2       | 2       | 7      
3       | 2       | 2 
3       | 2       | 6
```

User can replay game trying to achieve highest score..

I need query to take best "MAX" score per quiz played by user, and sort it by sum points of all quizes, and make to look it like this:

```
   user_id  | SUM(points) 
    --------+--------
    2       | 20             
    1       | 19
```

I've tried to do second part of it with this

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(points) 
FROM Quiz_list 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could show me how it should look as sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a subquery to get the `max()` and then do the `sum()`:

```
select user_id, sum(points) as sumpoints
from (select user_id, quiz_id, max(points) as points
      from quiz_list
      group by user_id, quiz_id
     ) uq
group by user_id
order by sumpoints desc;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de1136/1/0